# Can't connect to mongoose on test environment

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

I have a node application running in docker with mongodb and it works fine on development environment. However, I'm creating some tests with mocha and chai and I can't connect to mongo when I run these tests.

The function I want to test is:

```js
const Interactor = require("interactor");
const Donation = require("../models/donations");

module.exports = class CreateDonation extends Interactor {
  async run(context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.donation = new Donation.Model({
      donationId: context.id,
      status: context.status,
      amount: context.chargeInfo.donatedValue,
      donatorEmail: context.donatorInfo.email,
      source: context.source,
    });

    await this.donation.save();
  }

  rollback() {
    Donation.Model.findOneAndRemove({ donationId: this.context.id });
  }
};
```

My test:

```js
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
const CreateDonation = require("../../interactors/create-donation");
require("../../config/db");

const should = chai.should();
const { expect } = chai;

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe("CreateDonation", () => {
  it("Creates a donation when context passed is correct", async (done) => {
    const context = {
      id: "123123",
      status: "AUTHORIZED",
      chargeInfo: {
        donatedValue: 25.0,
      },
      donatorInfo: {
        email: "test@example.com",
      },
      source: "CREDIT_CARD",
    };
    const result = await CreateDonation.run(context);
    console.log(result);
    done();
  });
});
```

My db config file:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv/config");

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://db:27017/donations", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    reconnectInterval: 5000,
    reconnectTries: 50,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("good");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

module.exports = mongoose;
```

The error I get from the test above is:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing to import something?

Comment: please attach your docker-compose file and the commands you run for running the application and for testing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your services inside docker with a docker compose file, they'll get an hostname based on the name you wrote for the service inside the docker-compose file.

Example:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

In this example, the `web` service can reach the redis db at the redis `hostname`.

If you change the service name in this way:

```
  db:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

The web service must connect to the `db` host.

So, when you run the compose file, your the `db` service is reached with the `db` hostname from you app service. But when you run your tests outside a docker compose, the `db` hostname isn't available and you need to use localhost because your db is running on your OS directly (or it is running inside a container with the 27017 port mapped on the main host).

If you're using a unix OS, you can solve your problem adding an alias in your /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost db
```

In this way you can run your tests keeping the `db` connection string.

Otherwise, and this is the suggested solution, you can use an environment variable to change the connection string at the application startup:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
```

And run it using

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb://db:27017/donations npm start
```

Then in the docker compose you can add a fixed environment variable using this code:

```
environment:
  - MONGO_URI=mongodb://db:27017/donations
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that when testing, I need to use "localhost" on my connection string for mongo (I was using the name from docker-compose). So with the URI as "mongodb://localhost:27017/donations" it worked. I don't know why.